# I have problem in MySQL query with many subqueries and user defined variables

Tags: mysql, sorting, subquery, range, ip

I need to make a unionS of all intersecting ip ranges,
and then I need to check if individual ip adress is inside
some of this resulting ip ranges.

I have such table, it is just example
`mysql> select * from ips_test;`

```
`+----+-------------+------+------+
| id | ip          | flag | fol  |
+----+-------------+------+------+
|  1 | 10.10.10.10 | f    |   -1 |
|  2 | 10.10.10.18 | l    |    1 |
|  3 | 10.10.10.13 | f    |   -1 |
|  4 | 10.10.10.19 | l    |    1 |
|  5 | 10.10.10.20 | f    |   -1 |
|  6 | 10.10.10.22 | l    |    1 |
|  7 | 10.10.10.21 | f    |   -1 |
|  8 | 10.10.10.23 | l    |    1 |
|  9 | 10.10.10.11 | a    |    0 |
| 10 | 10.10.10.16 | a    |    0 |
| 11 | 10.10.10.18 | a    |    0 |
| 12 | 10.10.10.19 | a    |    0 |
| 13 | 10.10.10.26 | a    |    0 |
| 14 | 10.10.10.10 | a    |    0 |
+----+-------------+------+------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)`
```

here 'f' flag shows that this is start of the ip range,
'l' is end of the range and 'a' is individual ip adress.
'fol' is flag for my way of making big number of unions
of ip ranges that intersect with each other.

i can find theese unions by the next query

```
select ip, flag, fol, block_border from
(
select *,
IF(block_border=-1,@chain:=@chain+1,@chain:=0) as "min_one_chain" from
(
select * from
(
select *, sum(fol) over(order by ip_num) as block_border from
(select *, INET_ATON(ip) as ip_num from ips_test order by ip_num
) as sorted_fol
) as bl_border
where block_border=0 OR (block_border=-1 AND fol=-1)
) as almost_done, (select @chain:=0) as init
) as done where (min_one_chain=0 OR min_one_chain=1) AND (flag!='a');
```

with next output

```
+-------------+------+------+--------------+
| ip          | flag | fol  | block_border |
+-------------+------+------+--------------+
| 10.10.10.10 | f    |   -1 |           -1 |
| 10.10.10.19 | l    |    1 |            0 |
| 10.10.10.20 | f    |   -1 |           -1 |
| 10.10.10.23 | l    |    1 |            0 |
+-------------+------+------+--------------+
4 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

So i found what i need at this step, sorted ip ranges,
that are unions of all intersecting ones.

Next I need to output all ip adresses, but with
already unique and not-intersecting ip ranges and excluded
individual ip adresses that are inside these ranges.

and here I have problem, with next query

```
select ip, ip_num, flag, fol,
IF(flag='f', @range_inner:=1, @range_inner:=@range_inner) as "inner_f",
IF(flag='l', @range_inner:=0, @range_inner:=@range_inner) as "inner_l"
from
(
(select ip, flag, fol, INET_ATON(ip) as ip_num from ips_test where flag='a')
UNION
(
select ip, flag, fol, ip_num from
(
select *,
IF(block_border=-1,@chain:=@chain+1,@chain:=0) as "min_one_chain" from
(
select * from
(
select *, sum(fol) over(order by ip_num) as block_border from
(select *, INET_ATON(ip) as ip_num from ips_test order by ip_num
) as sorted_fol
) as bl_border
where block_border=0 OR (block_border=-1 AND fol=-1)
) as almost_done, (select @chain:=0) as init
) as done where min_one_chain=0 OR min_one_chain=1
) order by ip_num asc, fol asc
) as ordered_ips, (select @range_inner:=0) as init where "inner_l"=0 OR flag!='a';
```

which produce following output

```
+-------------+-----------+------+------+---------+---------+
| ip          | ip_num    | flag | fol  | inner_f | inner_l |
+-------------+-----------+------+------+---------+---------+
| 10.10.10.10 | 168430090 | f    |   -1 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.10 | 168430090 | a    |    0 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.11 | 168430091 | a    |    0 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.16 | 168430096 | a    |    0 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.18 | 168430098 | a    |    0 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.19 | 168430099 | a    |    0 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.19 | 168430099 | l    |    1 |       1 |       0 |
| 10.10.10.20 | 168430100 | f    |   -1 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.23 | 168430103 | l    |    1 |       1 |       0 |
| 10.10.10.26 | 168430106 | a    |    0 |       0 |       0 |
+-------------+-----------+------+------+---------+---------+
10 rows in set, 9 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

And this is what i want to get

```
+-------------+-----------+------+------+---------+---------+
| ip          | ip_num    | flag | fol  | inner_f | inner_l |
+-------------+-----------+------+------+---------+---------+
| 10.10.10.10 | 168430090 | f    |   -1 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.19 | 168430099 | l    |    1 |       1 |       0 |
| 10.10.10.20 | 168430100 | f    |   -1 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.23 | 168430103 | l    |    1 |       1 |       0 |
| 10.10.10.26 | 168430106 | a    |    0 |       0 |       0 |
+-------------+-----------+------+------+---------+---------+
10 rows in set, 9 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

With exclusion of

```
+-------------+-----------+------+------+---------+---------+
| ip          | ip_num    | flag | fol  | inner_f | inner_l |
+-------------+-----------+------+------+---------+---------+
| 10.10.10.10 | 168430090 | f    |   -1 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.10 | 168430090 | a    |    0 |       1 |       1 | !!!! theese
| 10.10.10.11 | 168430091 | a    |    0 |       1 |       1 | !!!! ip
| 10.10.10.16 | 168430096 | a    |    0 |       1 |       1 | !!!! adresses
| 10.10.10.18 | 168430098 | a    |    0 |       1 |       1 | !!!! which are inside 
| 10.10.10.19 | 168430099 | a    |    0 |       1 |       1 | !!!! ip range
| 10.10.10.19 | 168430099 | l    |    1 |       1 |       0 |
| 10.10.10.20 | 168430100 | f    |   -1 |       1 |       1 |
| 10.10.10.23 | 168430103 | l    |    1 |       1 |       0 |
| 10.10.10.26 | 168430106 | a    |    0 |       0 |       0 |
+-------------+-----------+------+------+---------+---------+
10 rows in set, 9 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

How can I solve this?

For more convenience I will provide table creation code
and insert statements

```
mysql> show create table ips_test;
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ips_test | CREATE TABLE `ips_test` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flag` enum('a','f','l') DEFAULT NULL,
  `fol` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And, INSERT statements

```
mysql> insert into for_ips.ips_test(ip,flag,fol) values('10.10.10.10','f',-1),('10.10.10.18','l',1),('10.10.10.13','f',-1),('10.10.10.19','l',1);

mysql> insert into for_ips.ips_test(ip,flag,fol) values('10.10.10.20','f',-1),('10.10.10.22','l',1),('10.10.10.21','f',-1),('10.10.10.23','l',1);

mysql> insert into ips_test(ip,flag,fol) values ('10.10.10.11','a',0),('10.10.10.16','a',0),('10.10.10.18','a',0),('10.10.10.19','a',0),('10.10.10.26','a',0);
```

Comment: When you want to use user-defined variables then you must use only the query which have only one data source (table, view or subquery), and the variables itself must be inited on the same level (as second datasource). Your "next query" tries to use UDV on different nesting levels - the result will be obviously incorrect.

Comment: @Akina, thank you very much. I am new in SQL querying, how can i do better? Make table from my first query, and use it for second stage, or ... what would you advise?

Comment: @Akina Also, i found one advise almost similar to my question, at this link https://qna.habr.com/q/453749, and there UDV are used in 2 subqueries. I still dont understand how this works

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either  with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Please indent code reasonably.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but this is not a good way to store data.  I would have separate fields for start and end of range.

Comment: @RohitGupta thanks, but then i dont know how to solve my goal, may be some advise? i need to find all intersecting ip ranges and output their unions, also need to exclude from output ips that are inside in some of ranges

Comment: *i found one advise almost similar to my question, at this link* Pay attention - each separate UDV is used on its own nesting level only. And there is no nesting level which uses 2 or more tables. This is the reason why the output result is correct.

Comment: It seems that you need in common collapse/union ranges algorithm, is it? If so then tell what is your MySQL version (the output for `SELECT VERSION();`)? Anycase the task can be solved without UDVs.

Comment: @Akina my MySQL version is 8.0.32. Thank you. But how can i solve this without UDV? I can not imagine still

Answer (score 0):

Collapsing IP ranges:

```
WITH 
cte1 AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         INET_ATON(ip) ip,
         SUM(CASE flag WHEN 'f' THEN 1
                       WHEN 'l' THEN -1
                       ELSE 0
                       END) OVER (ORDER BY ip) weight
  FROM ips_test
),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT ip, SUM(weight = 0) OVER (ORDER BY ip DESC) grp
  FROM cte1
)
SELECT INET_NTOA(MIN(ip)) ip_start,
       INET_NTOA(MAX(ip)) ip_end
FROM cte2
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY 1;
```

| ip_start | ip_end |
| --- | --- |
| 10.10.10.10 | 10.10.10.19 |
| 10.10.10.20 | 10.10.10.23 |
| 10.10.10.26 | 10.10.10.26 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y0AMJs4Q) with some explanations.

The output differs from your desired one, but I hope that you can edit outer query (or convert it to 3rd CTE and add another outer query) and obtain the output which you need in.

PS. The query assumes that your source data is consistent.

Comment: wow, nice! i did not even thought that it could be done so shortly and without many subqueries! Thank you very much!